# How to copy os.Stdout output to string variable

Tags: go, output

I have a function like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// PrintSomething prints some thing
func PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println("print something")
}

func main() {
    PrintSomething()
}
```

How do I wrap PrintSomething to another function call CaptureSomething to save the string "print something" to a variable and return it?

Comment: @Himanshu: How would that help?

Comment: @ThunderCat: All those solutions have fatal flaws.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create [pipe](https://godoc.org/os#Pipe) and set [stdout](https://godoc.org/os#Stdout) to the pipe writer. Start a goroutine to copy the pipe reader to a buffer.  When done, close the pipe writer and wait for goroutine to complete reading. Return the buffer as a string.

```
// capture replaces os.Stdout with a writer that buffers any data written 
// to os.Stdout. Call the returned function to cleanup and get the data
// as a string.
func capture() func() (string, error) {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    done := make(chan error, 1)

    save := os.Stdout
    os.Stdout = w

    var buf strings.Builder

    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(&buf, r)
        r.Close()
        done <- err
    }()

    return func() (string, error) {
        os.Stdout = save
        w.Close()
        err := <-done
        return buf.String(), err
    }
```

}

Use it like this:

```
done := capture()
fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
capturedOutput, err := done()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bG3opmVoOLy)

Comment: I'd make `done` transmit `error` instead of `struct{}` and would send on it the error returned from `io.Copy` or `r.Close`, if any, or just `nil` otherwise. Then I'd check what `<-done` returns. Well, in this case errors are unlikely but still it's better to blow up on an unexpected error than ignore it silently.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these, whichever works for you:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println("print something")
}

func PrintSomethingBig() {
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        fmt.Println("print something")
    }
}

func PrintSomethingOut(out io.Writer) {
    fmt.Fprintln(out, "print something to io.Writer")
}

func PrintSomethingString() string {
    return fmt.Sprintln("print something into a string")
}

// not thread safe
// modified by zlynx@acm.org from original at http://craigwickesser.com/2015/01/capture-stdout-in-go/
func captureStdout(f func()) string {
    old := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    go func() {
        f()
        w.Close()
    }()

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    // Will complete when the goroutine calls w.Close()
    io.Copy(buf, r)

    // Clean up.
    os.Stdout = old
    r.Close()

    return buf.String()
}

func main() {
    str1 := &strings.Builder{}
    str2 := PrintSomethingString()
    PrintSomethingOut(str1)
    PrintSomethingOut(os.Stdout)
    str3 := captureStdout(PrintSomething)
    str4 := captureStdout(PrintSomethingBig)
    fmt.Println("string 1 is", str1)
    fmt.Println("string 2 is", str2)
    fmt.Println("string 3 is", str3)
    fmt.Println("string 4 len", len(str4))
}
```

Comment: I you can't control the PrintSomething function, I need a technique to wrap it

Comment: @HauMa Added a capture wrap function.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// PrintSomething prints some thing
func PrintSomething() {
    fmt.Println("print something")
}

func CaptureSomething() (string, error) {
    defer func(stdout *os.File) {
        os.Stdout = stdout
    }(os.Stdout)
    out, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "stdout")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer out.Close()
    outname := out.Name()
    os.Stdout = out

    PrintSomething()

    err = out.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(outname)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    os.Remove(outname)
    return string(data), nil
}

func main() {
    s, err := CaptureSomething()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Print(s)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/O2kSegxYeGy

Output:

```
print something
```