# golang exec command: stream output to stdout *and* capture output in variable

Tags: go

I'm building a cli in go and have the following situation. I'm calling a bash command from go that prompts the user for a login, then prints a token after login. For example:

```
cmd := exec.Command("vault", "login", "-method=okta", "-format=json", "username=abc")
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdinout
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
_ = cmd.Run()
```

This streams the output nicely, but I have no way to parse the token from the command's output after the user logs in. I've tried to wrap the `cmd.Run()` into piping functions like [this](https://github.com/zenizh/go-capturer/blob/master/main.go) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183462/how-to-copy-os-stdout-output-to-string-variable) and [this](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-capture-text-return-from-exec-function-example) but in both cases the output returned is empty. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `os.Stdinout` so the code seems to be entered incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably lots of packages to do this, but it's not hard to whip up your own:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

type saveOutput struct {
    savedOutput []byte
}

func (so *saveOutput) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    so.savedOutput = append(so.savedOutput, p...)
    return os.Stdout.Write(p)
}

func main() {
    var so saveOutput
    cmd := exec.Command("factor", "999999")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = &so
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    _ = cmd.Run()
    fmt.Printf("I got this output: %s\n", so.savedOutput)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/T-o3QvGOm5q

Answer (score 2):

Don't make your structure for nothing.
Use bytes.Buffer

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("vault", "login", "-method=okta", "-format=json", "username=abc")
    cmd.Stdout = &buffer
    _ = cmd.Run()
    log.Printf("Vault login output: %s", buffer.String())
}
```